# Laravel Find Not working with custom primary key

Tags: laravel, primary-key

I am stuck with a situation where i coudn't update my records using Eloquent in Laravel 5.5 using custom primary key.
Here is what i tried :-
In my Model.php i have,

`protected $primarykey = 'custom_primary_key';`

my migrations looks like :-
`$table->increments('custom_primary_key');`

in my controller,i have :-

```
Model::find(custom_primary_key);
```

but when i tries to find a record using `find()` in my controller, it gives

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'table.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `table` where `table`.`id` = 1 and `table`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)"
```

table also contains a column with custom primary key and there is no column named `id`.

It doesnt recognize the cutom primary key. Where can i be missing something ?

Comment: try making K capital `$primaryKey`

Answer (score 2):

Set $primarykey into $primaryKey. Check the documentation from Laravel here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions